# Google Sheets - How might I get the last 5 wins / losses for each team?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

In Google sheets, I'd like to get the last five results for each team, a win/loss streak statistics (e.g. W,L,W,L,L)

My data looks like this:

```
team A | Win     | 21/02/2020 11:32:00
team B | Loss    | 09/03/2020 09:38:00
team C | Win     | 04/03/2020 14:07:00
team A | Loss    | 09/03/2020 16:58:00
team B | Win     | 29/01/2020 10:59:00
team C | Win     | 16/04/2020 11:27:00
```

the output I'd like is

```
team A | W | L |
team B | W | L |
team C | W | W |
```

I suspect there will be a lookup for the team name, a sort on the date, perhaps an index to get the last 5 dates.

What formula (combination) will I need to get this output?

Comment: Please provide a sample sheet, with a good volume of sample data, to make it easier for people to work on this.

Answer (score 0):

This formula should get you most of the way there.
If you have your data in A1:C, and a list of your unique team names in column D, put this formula in E1:

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY(A$1:C,"select A,B,C 
                              where A = '"&D1&"' order by C desc limit 5 " ,0),
           "select Col2 order by Col3"))
```

The inner query matches the team name, orders the data in descending date order, and selects the first five records (the five latest).

The outer query reverses the date order - newest at the end - and selects only the Win/Loss column.

This "column" is then transposed to go across as a row of data, for that specific team.

I'm not good at `REGEXREPLACE`, but this could easily covert WIN to W and Loss to L.  Or by using `SUBSTITUTE`.

And I'll see if I can make it into an ARRAYFORMULA.  As it is now, you copy the formula down.

Here is a sample sheet.